# Add new media format to spartacus mediaModel

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I added a new type of image format `3d` in my commercewebservices-spring.xml.
I want to access this new format in my product-images.component in Product Detail page, something like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="mainImage$ | async as main">
    <div *ngIf="main.3d as 3d">
```

But I get an 'unresolved variable', so I guess I need to add this new format elsewhere in spartacus or there is something I'm missing.

Could anyone help with this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of steps you'd need to do:

1. Make sure that the image has been exposed in the OCC api. The OCC endpoints has a configurable fields mapping, that you can use to control the response. You need to verify if your 3d property is exposed. I'm also not sure if you add this as a new property to the backend product model and if it's a media container or a media. But I assume you figure that out.
2. Make the Spartacus adapter aware of the new field mapping, this is documented in https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/#configuring-endpoints. You basically configure the required field, so that the data is requested and automatically stored inside the product state in Spartacus.
3. Implement the UI. I'm not sure if you like to add the 3d image as part of other thumbs/images, or that you need a dedicated UI for 3d images. If it's completely replacement of the product images, the easiest thing is to replace the current cms ProductImagesComponent mapping, i.e.:

```
providers: [
  provideDefaultConfig(<CmsConfig>{
    cmsComponents: {
      ProductImagesComponent: {
        component: Custom3dImagesComponent
      }
    }
  })
]
```

This is documented at https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/

There are alternatives for each step, but these are most straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at ProductImageNormalizer (https://sap.github.io/spartacus/injectables/ProductImageNormalizer.html#source) you can see that the mapping is slightly different: either image.primary.<format> or image.gallery[n].<format>

Also, bear in mind that the format codes used in the DTO are mapped in the SAP Commerce side. There is an ImageFormatMapping concept, which maps from the actual media format used in the data model in SAP Commerce to the format strings used in the DTO.